# Trying to use youtube api on html page

Tags: javascript, html, api, youtube, youtube-api

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" >
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showResponse(response){
        var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += responseString;
    }

    function onClientLoad(){
        gapi.client.load('youtube','v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
    }

    function onYouTubeApiLoad(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey('MyActualKey');

        search();
    }

    function search(){
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: 'snippet'
        });

        request.execute(onSearchResponse);
    }

    function onSearchResponse(response){
        showResponse(response);
    }

</script>
<title></title>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is from Codecademy, and I thought I can use it on an html page and it would work.
I got an API key from google and I set my Youtube data api v3 setting to enabled in my google developers console, but this code gives me a blank page.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because there's nothing in your body?

Comment: you need to include the code in your body or it will show nothing

Answer (score 0):

There are a few missing pieces, code snippets which codecademy likely took for granted but which are essential when placing it in your own server outside of their app. First of all, you need a line that actually loads the gapi library from google. You can put this in your code, just before the closing :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad"></script>
```

In short, this will get the library from Google's servers, and when it's loaded the library will automatically call your onClientLoad method, kicking off your app.

Next, you say you have an API key; make sure you put that key into your code by replacing this:

```
gapi.client.setApiKey('MyKey');
```

with this:

```
gapi.client.setApiKey('{WHATEVER_YOUR_ACTUAL_KEY IS');
```

Finally, as the commenters mentioned, your body is empty, so when your code executes the showResponse method there's no place to put what comes back. Add this:

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I actually have the key and placed it in the right place I just didn't want to show it here, I was only missing the script and the div but for some reason it still doesn't work.
I updated how my code looks like.